# Update a Ruby on Rails app to work on newer Heroku Stack

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, git-push

I had worked over a year ago on a Ruby on Rails app that was set up initially to run on Heroku Stack 18 which I have now learned is depricated. I am trying to get that app working again on a newer stack but whenever I try to push up it tells me that the Ruby version (2.5.1) does not exist. I would love some insight on how to upgrade my Ruby/Rails versions so that I don't need to make the project from scratch again. Thanks in advance.

When running the push to the heroku remote I get the following output:

```
Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
remote:        Running: rake assets:precompile
remote:        rake aborted!
remote:        ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 3, expected 2)
remote:        /tmp/build_fbf58a0c/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.8.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:111:in `initialize'
remote:        /tmp/build_fbf58a0c/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.8.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:37:in `new'
remote:        /tmp/build_fbf58a0c/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.8.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:37:in `build'
remote:        /tmp/build_fbf58a0c/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.8.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:101:in `block in build'
remote:        /tmp/build_fbf58a0c/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.8.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:101:in `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_fbf58a0c/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.8.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:101:in `inject'
remote:        /tmp/build_fbf58a0c/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.8.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:101:in `build'
remote:        /tmp/build_fbf58a0c/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/railties-5.2.8.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:510:in `block in app'
remote:        /tmp/build_fbf58a0c/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/railties-5.2.8.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:506:in `synchronize'
remote:        /tmp/build_fbf58a0c/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/railties-5.2.8.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:506:in `app'
remote:        /tmp/build_fbf58a0c/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/railties-5.2.8.1/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:47:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
remote:        /tmp/build_fbf58a0c/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/railties-5.2.8.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
remote:        /tmp/build_fbf58a0c/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/railties-5.2.8.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
remote:        /tmp/build_fbf58a0c/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/railties-5.2.8.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
remote:        /tmp/build_fbf58a0c/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/railties-5.2.8.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
remote:        /tmp/build_fbf58a0c/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/railties-5.2.8.1/lib/rails/application.rb:361:in `initialize!'
remote:        /tmp/build_fbf58a0c/config/environment.rb:5:in `<main>'
remote:        <internal:/tmp/build_fbf58a0c/vendor/ruby-3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
remote:        <internal:/tmp/build_fbf58a0c/vendor/ruby-3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
remote:        /tmp/build_fbf58a0c/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/bootsnap-1.16.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require'
remote:        /tmp/build_fbf58a0c/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/railties-5.2.8.1/lib/rails/application.rb:337:in `require_environment!'
remote:        /tmp/build_fbf58a0c/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/railties-5.2.8.1/lib/rails/application.rb:520:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
remote:        /tmp/build_fbf58a0c/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.4.2/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:61:in `block (2 levels) in define'
remote:        Tasks: TOP => environment
remote:        (See full trace by running task with --trace)
remote: 
remote:  !
remote:  !     Precompiling assets failed.
remote:  !
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the oldest supported Ruby on Heroku is version 3.0.6 [on Heroku-20](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-support#supported-runtimes), and you are on Rails 5.2. According to this [compatibility table](https://www.fastruby.io/blog/ruby/rails/versions/compatibility-table.html), you should reach Rails 6.1 for Ruby 3.

For Rails upgrades, it's best to follow [the official guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html), doing it version-by-version and ensuring the correct behaviour.

Same for Ruby, I recommend [this guide](https://rubyreferences.github.io/rubychanges/), checking out what has changed from one version to another and modifying your code if necessary.

Comment: Thanks a lot I didn't realize that I had to do them both in conjunction I thought one would cascade to fix the other. Now I just need to figure out why my application ins't showing up despite the successful push and no errors in the log.

Comment: @PresleyThe3 glad to hear it. Does it work locally? I had a similar issue, everything worked fine except in production / Docker, also the log was empty. The missing piece was the secret key.